# Why would a DBF show as a bad record in PHP but not when viewed directly?

Tags: php, database, error-handling, dbf, dbase

I am using the dBase extension of PHP to analyze a DBF but there's an entire mid-section of the DBF that returns an error ("tried to read bad record") when I try to view the rows with dbase_get_records_with_names(), but when I look at the specific records in DBF Viewer, they seem perfectly fine just like any other records.

What might be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably data that is not 100% correct, but the viewer program ignores it.  Such as null bytes an a Char field, or something besides a space (' ') or asterisk ('*') in the delete column.

Comment: I'm not aware of any easy way to do so.  If you know the spec you can open the dbf file in an editor and look at the affected records and fix from there (easy to make mistakes, though).  Can you share the dbf?

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on [your other posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241425/is-there-a-size-limit-to-opening-files-in-php/18254347#18254347)

It may not be a standard .dbf file since they were typically only supported to 2 gig file limit under 32-bit O/S.  May need to look into Sybase Database-Advantage-Server.