# Is there a size limit to opening files in PHP?

Tags: php, database, dbf

I am using a dbase extension in PHP to open up a large DBF of 4.5+ GB but it seems to give bum records from 9.6 million onward even though the database looks perfectly fine in any viewer, etc.

Do I need to somehow crank up a memory limit somewhere?

Comment: open how? and probably.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dbase-open.php

Comment: Which platform? Might be a max int/addressing issue..

Comment: 32-bit PHP has a 2GB filesize limit for the filepointer: to access files larger than that, you'll need a 64-bit PHP version that can use a 64-bit filepointer: not sure if that applies to the dbase extension

Comment: I think you need to increase the memory limit in the php.ini file. You could also try increasing the time limit using `set_time_limit();`

Comment: I can't offert a complete appropriate answer but my first guest would be that you will at least have to check your php.ini config for the  'max_execution_time'of your scripts, assuming opening up these large files will take a while. memory_limit will also probably have to be upgraded.

Comment: 9.6 million is too small to be overflowing the record offset... I'm thinking that there might be an integer overflow in the library itself. Try to get dbase_numrecords to see if it returns the expected record count.

Comment: 2 seconds for outputting a 4.5 GB file? Wow. What kind of harddisk do you have?

Comment: @MarkBaker I think you may be right. The 10-mil subset database is just over 2 GB. Crap. I don't know what to do now.

Comment: I assume you're on a 64-bit OS, else the problem could be even more fundamental

Comment: Maybe/hopefully the problem is in the dbase function. If so, maybe you can find or write your own version of it. The dbf file format is fairly easy to read.

Comment: You'd need the `x64` downloads; but looks like the dbase extension isn't available as a 64-bit build

Comment: @Mark Baker is only artially correct about the file thing - you can compile a 32 bit PHP with large file support - but in the case of DBF file access is mediated by the extension - which needs to have an intrinsic understanding of large files - i.e. it might work, it might not.

Comment: Resource for 2GB limit of 32-bit PHP reported by MarkBaker: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Answer (score 0):

try setting limits on the number of records on show, use **pagination** and limit to about 15, this should help. I have never heard of PHP not opening a file because of size however you could be putting too much data on a page and causing an overflow.

Comment: They are already using pagination, because the alternative would be to read 10 million records at once. That would not result in just "bum records from 9.6 million onward".

Answer (score 0):

You mention a 4.5 gig "dbf" database file.  From a historical development of dBASE (way back), and FoxPro / Visual FoxPro, they were based one 32-bit O/S and the maximum individual file size was 2 gig.  By having a 4.5 gig, I would suspect the .dbf is handled by another program... Such as Sybase Database-Advantage-Server which supports and extends older .dbf formats and allows exceeding that 2 gig file limit.  I would make sure which database connection handlers you are working with.